# does __new__ over ride __init__ in python

Tags: python, init, derived-class, base-class

I have the following code:

```
class Demo:
    def __new__(self):
        self.__init__(self)
        print("Demo's __new__() invoked")
    def __init__(self):
        print("Demo's __init__() invoked")
                      
class Derived_Demo(Demo):
    def __new__(self):
        print("Derived_Demo's __new__() invoked")
    def __init__(self):
        print("Derived_Demo's __init__() invoked")

def main():
    obj1 = Derived_Demo()
    obj2 = Demo()

main()
```

I'm trying to understand the order of execution:

1. __new__ in the derived class is called first
2. why doesn't  _*init*_ in the derived  class called next?

Comment: In  Derived, you need to call `super().__init__()`

Comment: the code above runs fine. it doesn't explicitly call super().__init__  -> is new in the derive class automatically followed by new in the base class? –

Comment: This code absolute does NOT run fine.  It's producing `None`s rather than actual instances of your classes, due to the malformed `__new__()` methods.

Comment: I just ran it and it prints out  Derived_Demo's __new__() invoked
Demo's __init__() invoked
Demo's __new__() invoked

Comment: not failing is not the same as running correctly.

Comment: I understand that.  I'm just trying to figure out the order of execution

Comment: Derived `__new__` gets called due to `obj1` line.  You don't return anything so `obj1=None`.  Demo `__new__` gets called due to `obj2`.  *You* call Demo `__init__` before printing Demo `__new__ ` was called and return nothing so `obj2=None`.

Comment: You should do `print(obj1,obj2)` inside `main` to show that the code is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fundamentally broken, which is why `__init__` isn't being invoked as expected.

Per [the docs for `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__):

> If `__new__()` does not return an instance of *cls*, then the new instance’s `__init__()` method will not be invoked.

Your `__new__` doesn't explicitly return anything, so it's returning `None`.

If you write it correctly (including removing explicit calls to `__init__` within `__new__`, and explicitly delegating up the inheritance chain for `Derived_Demo`'s `__new__` *and* `__init__`), you code will work as expected:

```
class Demo:
    def __new__(cls):
        print("Demo's __new__() invoked")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("Demo's __init__() invoked")

class Derived_Demo(Demo):
    def __new__(cls):
        print("Derived_Demo's __new__() invoked")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    def __init__(self):
        print("Derived_Demo's __init__() invoked")
        super().__init__()

def main():
    obj1 = Derived_Demo()
    obj2 = Demo()

main()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vY87DsIwEER7n8JKg90gAR0SHfew8tkIg7OObCeI05s4ifNBKKJiii1mZ/dp6pe7aTx5n6vUWnqFSp8J7VRASYVAeArBcmX54AbVRqJjSYju7JThVGKrH1AkfEoacI1BapsaDOP75bsFQ6J0nWtBlRuUMfUNsxaJTYxsoRDhAQuD/9xrPvxHvw/aRs@ZE0OEBESVSmTja53dD/Sybs/j5thveocMR96/AQ)

Which outputs:

```
Derived_Demo's __new__() invoked
Demo's __new__() invoked
Derived_Demo's __init__() invoked
Demo's __init__() invoked
Demo's __new__() invoked
Demo's __init__() invoked
```

where `super()` based dispatch completely runs all the `__new__`(s) *then* all the `__init__`(s) are run on the resulting object produced by `__new__`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an execution order that should make better sense given the output you are seeing.

1. `"Derived_Demo's __new__() invoked"` - because you instantiate `Derived_Demo`, and `__new__` will always be called first.
2. Your `Derived_Demo.__new__` returns `None`, meaning before arriving at `Derived_Demo.__init__`, `obj1` is `None` (put a `print(obj1)` immediately after it is defined to see).
3. `"Demo's __init__() invoked"` - because `Demo.__new__` is called first, but you expliclity call `__init__` in `__new__` (which is an anti-pattern but Python doesn't disallow it).
4. `"Demo's __new__() invoked"` - to be expected after `__init__` is called.

Answer (score 1):

If you went and overriden `__new__()` correctly then you'd see a very different order of execution:

```
class Demo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Demo's __new__() invoked")
        return super(Demo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)    
    def __init__(self):
        print("Demo's __init__() invoked")
                      
class Derived_Demo(Demo):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Derived_Demo's __init__() invoked")

def main():
    obj1 = Derived_Demo()
    obj2 = Demo()

    # this also creates instances correctly
    print(obj1, obj2)

main()
>>> Demo's __new__() invoked
>>> Derived_Demo's __init__() invoked
>>> Demo's __new__() invoked
>>> Demo's __init__() invoked

>>> <__main__.Derived_Demo object at 0x00000213C0E2BB20> <__main__.Demo object at 0x00000213C0EE5BA0>
```